# R plot confidence interval directly from data, no calculation needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, confidence-interval

How can I add confidence interval bars to a scatterplot?

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Year   Estimate   LowerCI    UpperCI
2010   1000       750        1250
2020   2000       1500       2500
```

And I have made a scatterplot as follow:

[image: scatter]

How can I add confidence interval bars to my plot just use information given in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(Year), y = Estimate, ymin = LowerCI, ymax = UpperCI)) +
  geom_pointrange()
```

You could also use `geom_errorbar()`, `geom_crossbar()`, or `geom_linerange()`: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_linerange.html